# $.get() remote HTML causes unwanted requests for that page's resources

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am fetching a remote page's HTML and returning the HTML to review meta tags and I notice unexpected failed requests for all the remote assets in the other page's HTML whenever I assign that to a variable.

```
$.get(url, function(data, status) {
  var dt = $(data);
}
```

By the time I've assigned that variable, it triggers all these remote requests.

How can I avoid the the fact that assigning this data to a variable in the DOM seems to trip a request for every image or resource on that remote page!

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Is that all the relevant code?

Comment: Perhaps `$.get(\`${url} head\`, function(data) { console.log(data) })`

Comment: I am using a CORS-anywhere process to pass through the data but the URL would just look like a local URL passing a remote URL which returns that response  //myhost:8081/http://medium.com/@blogpage My suspicion is that when I assign this HTML to the variable it is part of the DOM which then triggers unwanted requests. But I surely must be able to filter this text without this happening?

Comment: var title = dt.filter('title').text();
       var description = dt.filter("meta[name='description']").attr('content');
Is all I'm trying to run

Answer (score 1):

When you do `$(data)`, jQuery ends up parsing the hTML and causes the requests to be made for the resources.

To get around it, use [DOM parser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) so the resources are not fetched.

```js
const myHTMLSource = `
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="title" content="Foo Bar">
    <meta name="description" content="FOO FOO">
    <meta name="keywords" content="bar, egg, bacon">
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="language" content="English">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"><\/script>
  </head>
  </body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
  </body>
</html>`;

const parser = new DOMParser();
const testDoc = parser.parseFromString(myHTMLSource, "text/html")
const metaTags = testDoc.querySelectorAll("meta");
console.log(metaTags.length);
```

Since being asked how to use in in the jQuery Ajax request, it just uses data:

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: url,
  method: "GET",
  dataType: "text"
}).done(function( data ) {
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const testDoc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/html")
  const metaTags = testDoc.querySelectorAll("meta");
  console.log(metaTags.length);
}).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

Comment: Where is this getting HTML from a remote file?

Comment: @mplungjan Really? Um, it uses the `data` variable which has the HTML source.

Comment: So OP says, GETTING the html, results in the requests inside the result are executed when doing `$(data)`. So the issue is to NOT use `$(data)` but the raw HTML but that means some kind of split on `</head>` BEFORE creating a DOM fragment

Comment: jQuery is making the HTTP requests when it parses the DOM

Comment: Yes, that is OP's problem. See my answer for a suggested solution

Comment: The DOM parser is not making the requests.

Comment: You still need to GET the remote page

Comment: This solution worked. Use a DOMParser class to avoid adding objects to the DOM where, apparently, JQuery decides to fetch them. However it happens, this method resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So you claim: GETTING the html results in the requests inside the result are executed when doing `$(data)`. So the issue is to NOT use `$(data)` but the raw HTML but that means some kind of split on `</head>` BEFORE creating a DOM fragment

Try this:

Uncomment the comments and remove the string I use for testing

```js
//$.get(url, function(data, status) { // uncomment
//  const dt = data.split("</head>")[0]
  const fragment = document.createElement("div");
// fragment.innerHTML = dt;

// test
  fragment.innerHTML = `<html>\n<head>\n<meta name="title" content="Foo Bar">\n<meta name="description" content="FOO FOO">\n<meta name="keywords" content="bar, egg, bacon">\n<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">\n<meta name="language" content="English">\n<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"><\/script>`; 

  [...fragment.querySelectorAll("meta")]
    .forEach(meta => {
      console.log([...meta.attributes]
        .map(attr => `${attr.nodeName}: ${attr.nodeValue}`))
  })
//}}
```